# apache http server directive

Tags: apache2

I would like apache to abort any request that takes the server more than 10sec to process the request. Can anyone tell me what directive to use. Is it the Timeout Directive

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is using the `Timeout` directive.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout

But 10 seconds is really very less. Are you sure you want to keep it so low?

The default is 300 (5 minutes)